# Minimal TCP client-server: accept() never receives a connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, mingw, winsock

I copied the example code for the book *TCP/IP Sockets in C* from http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/winsock.html and got it to compile on MinGW (without warnings by changing clntLen from unsigned int to int and void main to int main).

```sh
$ gcc.exe -Wall -o TCPEchoServerWS TCPEchoServerWS.c HandleTCPClientWS.c DieWithErrorWS.c -lws2_32
$ gcc.exe -o TCPEchoClientWS TCPEchoClientWS.c DieWithErrorWS.c -lws2_32
```

When I run the executables the server but not the client triggers a Windows firewall notification.

```sh
$ ./TCPEchoServerWS.exe 5000
inside for loop
$ ./TCPEchoClientWS.exe  169.1.1.1 "Echo this" 5000
connect() failed: 10060
```

The from printf debugging

```c
    for (;;) /* Run forever */
    {
        printf("inside for loop");
        clntLen = sizeof(echoClntAddr);
        if ((clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, &clntLen)) < 0)
            DieWithError("accept() failed");
        printf("Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(echoClntAddr.sin_addr));
```

it appears that the accept() never returns. I assume this is because it never has a connection to extract?? Any ideas please? I've also tried linking with -lwsock32, and disabling windows firewall.

Comment: "*When I run the executables the server but not the client triggers a Windows firewall notification*" - as it should be. By default, a firewall is more concerned about inbound connections than outbound connections, so it will usually block a server but rarely a client, unless configured otherwise. Did you tell the firewall to allow the port the server is trying to listen on? Winsock error 10060 is `WSAETIMEDOUT`, which is a good indication that `connect()` is not even reaching the server, such has if the firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I had tried disabling the firewall, and have just added an inbound rule which didn't work. When I netstat -a the server appears as TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           DESKTOP----------      LISTENING and so I tried $ ./TCPEchoClientWS.exe  0.0.0.0 "Echo this" 5000
connect() failed: 10049

Comment: Error 10049 is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`. `0.0.0.0` is the **IPv4 wildcard IP**. You can `bind()` an IPv4 socket to it, ie to bind a server to listen on all local IPv4 addrs, but an IPv4 client can't `connect()` to it, only to a real IPv4 addr. When the server is bound to a specific IP, the client must `connect()` to that specific IP (or an IP that port-forwards to it, such as a router's WAN IP). When the server is bound to the wildcard IP, the client can `connect()` to any IP that belongs to the server machine (or any IP that port-forwards to it). Use `ipconfig` on the server to see its local IPs.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me @RemyLebeau. I after trying all the addresses I got from `ipconfig` I tried 127.0.0.1 and it worked.

Comment: that proves that your client can connect to your server in general. If you still can't connect to your server outside of localhost then you clearly have network routing issues, not coding issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong IP (I just copied the one from the command it the book).

I just needed to use the IPv4 address from `ipconfig` as Remy suggested.